# WSL 2 copying character device file with preserve attributes fail

Tags: permissions, windows-subsystem-for-linux, cp

I have Windows 2004 update and have installed WSL2. I am running Debian distribution and I have noticed that copy with preserve-permissions fail for character device files. Below is what I have done:

```
test@DESKTOP-8TNVE8F:/mnt/c$ cd ~
test@DESKTOP-8TNVE8F:~$sudo cp -Trpfx /dev/ ~/myTest
```

This results in following:

```
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/tty1’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/kmsg’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ptmx’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/random’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/urandom’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/null’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/tty’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/tty0’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/zero’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/lxss’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS0’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS1’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS2’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS3’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS4’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS5’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS6’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS7’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS8’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS9’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS10’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS11’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS12’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS13’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS14’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS15’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS16’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS17’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS18’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS19’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS20’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS21’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS22’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS23’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS24’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS25’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS26’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS27’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS28’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS29’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS30’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS31’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS32’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS33’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS34’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS35’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS36’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS37’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS38’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS39’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS40’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS41’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS42’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS43’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS44’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS45’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS46’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS47’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS48’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS49’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS50’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS51’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS52’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS53’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS54’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS55’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS56’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS57’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS58’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS59’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS60’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS61’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS62’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS63’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS64’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS65’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS66’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS67’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS68’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS69’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS70’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS71’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS72’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS73’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS74’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS75’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS76’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS77’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS78’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS79’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS80’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS81’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS82’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS83’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS84’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS85’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS86’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS87’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS88’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS89’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS90’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS91’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS92’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS93’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS94’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS95’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS96’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS97’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS98’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS99’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS100’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS101’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS102’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS103’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS104’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS105’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS106’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS107’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS108’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS109’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS110’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS111’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS112’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS113’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS114’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS115’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS116’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS117’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS118’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS119’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS120’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS121’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS122’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS123’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS124’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS125’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS126’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS127’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS128’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS129’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS130’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS131’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS132’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS133’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS134’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS135’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS136’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS137’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS138’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS139’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS140’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS141’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS142’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS143’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS144’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS145’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS146’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS147’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS148’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS149’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS150’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS151’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS152’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS153’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS154’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS155’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS156’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS157’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS158’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS159’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS160’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS161’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS162’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS163’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS164’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS165’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS166’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS167’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS168’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS169’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS170’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS171’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS172’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS173’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS174’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS175’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS176’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS177’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS178’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS179’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS180’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS181’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS182’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS183’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS184’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS185’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS186’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS187’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS188’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS189’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS190’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/ttyS191’: Operation not permitted
cp: preserving permissions for ‘/home/test/myTest/tty2’: Operation not permitted
```

Is it some known limitation of WSL2 and is there a workaround/fix for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onoma@:~$ sudo cp -Trpfx /dev/ ~/myTest
onoma@:~$ ll myTest/
total 32
drwxr-xr-x  8 root  root      4096 Jun  8 16:07 ./
drwxr-xr-x 10 onoma onoma     4096 Jun  8 16:11 ../
crw-r--r--  1 root  root   10, 235 Jun  5 23:42 autofs
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root      4096 Jun  5 23:42 block/
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root      4096 Jun  8 16:07 bsg/
crw-------  1 root  root   10, 234 Jun  5 23:42 btrfs-control
crw-------  1 root  root    5,   1 Jun  5 23:42 console
crw-------  1 root  root   10,  62 Jun  5 23:42 cpu_dma_latency
crw-------  1 root  root   10, 203 Jun  5 23:42 cuse
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root        13 Jun  5 23:42 fd -> /proc/self/fd/
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  root    1,   7 Jun  5 23:42 full
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  root   10, 229 Jun  5 23:42 fuse
crw-r--r--  1 root  root    1,  11 Jun  5 23:42 kmsg
crw-------  1 root  root   10, 237 Jun  5 23:42 loop-control
brw-------  1 root  root    7,   0 Jun  5 23:42 loop0
brw-------  1 root  root    7,   1 Jun  5 23:42 loop1
brw-------  1 root  root    7,   2 Jun  5 23:42 loop2
brw-------  1 root  root    7,   3 Jun  5 23:42 loop3
brw-------  1 root  root    7,   4 Jun  5 23:42 loop4
brw-------  1 root  root    7,   5 Jun  5 23:42 loop5
brw-------  1 root  root    7,   6 Jun  5 23:42 loop6
brw-------  1 root  root    7,   7 Jun  5 23:42 loop7
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root      4096 Jun  5 23:42 mapper/
crw-------  1 root  root    1,   1 Jun  5 23:42 mem
crw-------  1 root  root   10,  59 Jun  5 23:42 memory_bandwidth
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root      4096 Jun  5 23:42 net/
crw-------  1 root  root   10,  61 Jun  5 23:42 network_latency
crw-------  1 root  root   10,  60 Jun  5 23:42 network_throughput
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  root    1,   3 Jun  5 23:42 null
crw-------  1 root  root   10, 144 Jun  5 23:42 nvram
crw-------  1 root  root  108,   0 Jun  5 23:42 ppp
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  root    5,   2 Jun  8 16:11 ptmx
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root      4096 Jun  5 23:42 pts/
brw-------  1 root  root    1,   0 Jun  5 23:42 ram0
brw-------  1 root  root    1,   1 Jun  5 23:42 ram1
brw-------  1 root  root    1,  10 Jun  5 23:42 ram10
brw-------  1 root  root    1,  11 Jun  5 23:42 ram11
brw-------  1 root  root    1,  12 Jun  5 23:42 ram12
brw-------  1 root  root    1,  13 Jun  5 23:42 ram13
brw-------  1 root  root    1,  14 Jun  5 23:42 ram14
brw-------  1 root  root    1,  15 Jun  5 23:42 ram15
brw-------  1 root  root    1,   2 Jun  5 23:42 ram2
brw-------  1 root  root    1,   3 Jun  5 23:42 ram3
brw-------  1 root  root    1,   4 Jun  5 23:42 ram4
brw-------  1 root  root    1,   5 Jun  5 23:42 ram5
brw-------  1 root  root    1,   6 Jun  5 23:42 ram6
brw-------  1 root  root    1,   7 Jun  5 23:42 ram7
brw-------  1 root  root    1,   8 Jun  5 23:42 ram8
brw-------  1 root  root    1,   9 Jun  5 23:42 ram9
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  root    1,   8 Jun  5 23:42 random
crw-------  1 root  root  251,   0 Jun  5 23:42 rtc0
brw-------  1 root  root    8,   0 Jun  5 23:42 sda
brw-------  1 root  root    8,  16 Jun  5 23:42 sdb
brw-------  1 root  root    8,  32 Jun  5 23:42 sdc
brw-------  1 root  root    8,  48 Jun  8 16:07 sdd
crw-------  1 root  root   21,   0 Jun  5 23:42 sg0
crw-------  1 root  root   21,   1 Jun  5 23:42 sg1
crw-------  1 root  root   21,   2 Jun  5 23:42 sg2
crw-------  1 root  root   21,   3 Jun  8 16:07 sg3
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root         8 Jun  5 23:42 shm -> /run/shm/
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root        15 Jun  5 23:42 stderr -> /proc/self/fd/2
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root        15 Jun  5 23:42 stdin -> /proc/self/fd/0
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root  root        15 Jun  5 23:42 stdout -> /proc/self/fd/1
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  root    5,   0 Jun  8 16:08 tty
crw-------  1 root  root    4,   0 Jun  5 23:42 tty0
crw-------  1 root  root    4,   1 Jun  5 23:42 tty1
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  10 Jun  5 23:42 tty10
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  11 Jun  5 23:42 tty11
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  12 Jun  5 23:42 tty12
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  13 Jun  5 23:42 tty13
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  14 Jun  5 23:42 tty14
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  15 Jun  5 23:42 tty15
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  16 Jun  5 23:42 tty16
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  17 Jun  5 23:42 tty17
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  18 Jun  5 23:42 tty18
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  19 Jun  5 23:42 tty19
crw-------  1 root  root    4,   2 Jun  5 23:42 tty2
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  20 Jun  5 23:42 tty20
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  21 Jun  5 23:42 tty21
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  22 Jun  5 23:42 tty22
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  23 Jun  5 23:42 tty23
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  24 Jun  5 23:42 tty24
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  25 Jun  5 23:42 tty25
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  26 Jun  5 23:42 tty26
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  27 Jun  5 23:42 tty27
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  28 Jun  5 23:42 tty28
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  29 Jun  5 23:42 tty29
crw-------  1 root  root    4,   3 Jun  5 23:42 tty3
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  30 Jun  5 23:42 tty30
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  31 Jun  5 23:42 tty31
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  32 Jun  5 23:42 tty32
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  33 Jun  5 23:42 tty33
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  34 Jun  5 23:42 tty34
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  35 Jun  5 23:42 tty35
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  36 Jun  5 23:42 tty36
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  37 Jun  5 23:42 tty37
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  38 Jun  5 23:42 tty38
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  39 Jun  5 23:42 tty39
crw-------  1 root  root    4,   4 Jun  5 23:42 tty4
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  40 Jun  5 23:42 tty40
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  41 Jun  5 23:42 tty41
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  42 Jun  5 23:42 tty42
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  43 Jun  5 23:42 tty43
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  44 Jun  5 23:42 tty44
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  45 Jun  5 23:42 tty45
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  46 Jun  5 23:42 tty46
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  47 Jun  5 23:42 tty47
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  48 Jun  5 23:42 tty48
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  49 Jun  5 23:42 tty49
crw-------  1 root  root    4,   5 Jun  5 23:42 tty5
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  50 Jun  5 23:42 tty50
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  51 Jun  5 23:42 tty51
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  52 Jun  5 23:42 tty52
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  53 Jun  5 23:42 tty53
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  54 Jun  5 23:42 tty54
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  55 Jun  5 23:42 tty55
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  56 Jun  5 23:42 tty56
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  57 Jun  5 23:42 tty57
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  58 Jun  5 23:42 tty58
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  59 Jun  5 23:42 tty59
crw-------  1 root  root    4,   6 Jun  5 23:42 tty6
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  60 Jun  5 23:42 tty60
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  61 Jun  5 23:42 tty61
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  62 Jun  5 23:42 tty62
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  63 Jun  5 23:42 tty63
crw-------  1 root  root    4,   7 Jun  5 23:42 tty7
crw-------  1 root  root    4,   8 Jun  5 23:42 tty8
crw-------  1 root  root    4,   9 Jun  5 23:42 tty9
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  64 Jun  5 23:42 ttyS0
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  65 Jun  5 23:42 ttyS1
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  66 Jun  5 23:42 ttyS2
crw-------  1 root  root    4,  67 Jun  5 23:42 ttyS3
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  root    1,   9 Jun  5 23:42 urandom
crw-------  1 root  root    7,   0 Jun  5 23:42 vcs
crw-------  1 root  root    7,   1 Jun  5 23:42 vcs1
crw-------  1 root  root    7, 128 Jun  5 23:42 vcsa
crw-------  1 root  root    7, 129 Jun  5 23:42 vcsa1
crw-------  1 root  root    7,  64 Jun  5 23:42 vcsu
crw-------  1 root  root    7,  65 Jun  5 23:42 vcsu1
drwxr-xr-x  2 root  root      4096 Jun  5 23:42 vfio/
crw-------  1 root  root   10, 238 Jun  5 23:42 vhost-net
crw-------  1 root  root   10,  63 Jun  5 23:42 vsock
crw-rw-rw-  1 root  root    1,   5 Jun  5 23:42 zero
```

Can't reproduce in Ubuntu 20.04. Make sure  you are running a WSL2 instance (wsl.exe -l -v) and your user is from the sudo group.

Comment: Thanks. Below is what am doing


`PS C:\Users\mooni> wsl.exe -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* Debian                 Stopped         1
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
  Ubuntu-18.04           Running         1
  docker-desktop         Running         2
PS C:\Users\mooni> ubuntu1804.exe
mentor@DESKTOP-8TNVE8F:~$ groups mentor
mentor : mentor adm dialout cdrom floppy sudo audio dip video plugdev netdev
mentor@DESKTOP-8TNVE8F:~$ sudo cp -Trpfx /dev/ ~/myTest
errors`

Comment: Thanks @onoma. I noticed that my distro was at version 1. Thanks for the tip. It worked. I  have accepted your answer